# Harnessing the TeX compiler to write a TeX to UTF8 converter

Tags: hyperref, unicode, tex4ht, pandoc

Dealing with most of one's text in UTF-8 rather than TeX-strings has many advantages, it is not only easy on the eyes, fingers and editors, but also it becomes real easy to feed your text to spellers, grammar checkers and other analyzers.... just imagine writing this string

```
 ĄąĆćĘę£łŃńÓóŚś-źŻż
```

Using simple search/replace strategies can be disastrous because of things like:

```
 \def\L{\matbb{L}}
```

leaving errors buried deep down converted files. Not to mention how deep the definition of the character could be buried in.

I understand that one can uniquely identify the characters (like in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74835/namethatchar-macro/74842#74842)) and that **pandoc**, **tex4ht** and **hyperref** deal with this problem at some level. My question is: How feasible would be to implement such converter in TeX itself?

(added by David)

input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zzz{hello}

\begin{document}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\renewcommand\L{LLL}
\renewcommand\"[1]{#1#1}
\renewcommand\c{c}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\end{document}
```

Converted to form with UTF-8 text runs but macro usage in place:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zzz{hello}

\begin{document}

Łööķ \zzz

\renewcommand\L{LLL}
\renewcommand\"[1]{#1#1}
\renewcommand\c{c}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: tricky really.  You have to decide what you want to do with macros, if you allow them all to expand then you could fairly easily get the utf8 text stream of resulting text, but then you have lost all your markup. If you don't allow them to expand, converting text inside macros is harder. I would be tempted to not allow the macros to expand and just fix up the main document text, any text inserted by macros can be fixed up by converting your style files (things like table of contents and other fixed strings)  tex4ht pandoc  have the advantage that they don't need to keep the original markup

Comment: of course whether it's easier to use utf8 depends a lot on your editing enviornment, I could far more easily type the tex input for the string that you show than the utf8.

Comment: A desirable translation is one that does not expand, ideally one would like to deal with the sources later in some other capacity. \O, \L, etc... have their standard meaning in LaTeX, but the value in a document depends on what is the preamble (and elsewhere). Does anyone knows the mechanism that **hyperref** uses to get them into Bookmarks?

Comment: hyperref essentially treats the bookmark string as a font encoding so switches to PU encoding and then all latex encoding specific commands  expand to the right thing, but note that it does this while expanding macros so at the same time it is losing all markup in the original document.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the question: what are you trying to achieve? With Unicode-aware engines (XeTeX, LuaTeX) you can just type `ĄąĆćĘę£łŃńÓóŚś-źŻż` in your `.tex` file. Are you trying to write a converter that will take text like ``\`A`` that someone else wrote in their `.tex` file, and convert that to UTF-8, using TeX? But if so the linked question seems to answer exactly that… or you're trying to take a `.tex` file containing text like ``\`A``, and produce a new `.tex` file in which that's changed to `À`, but everything else is intact?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think the OP wants that last, I added a complete example to the question (which of course the OP can remove if that is not what is meant)

Comment: Is "use emacs" a valid answer?  Set the `input-mode` to TeX and it will do the conversion for you.  (I did this for a while, before I realised that actually I *prefer* the TeX code to unicode.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR David Carlisle example is to the point. Exactly what is asked.

Comment: @Loop Space, please see the example by David in the question -- I am not an Emacs user, but I am pretty sure it doesn't do that.

Comment: @PauloNey Great, I have a solution that works at least for the example in the question :-) (And can be made to work for a lot more)

Comment: @PauloNey Emacs does **exactly** that.  ShreevatsaR explains how to get it to do so at the start of their answer.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, if you prefer input like `ĄąĆćĘę£łŃńÓóŚś-źŻż` in your `.tex` file, then you can simply type (or paste) that in. All you need is either `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if you're using pdfTeX, or not even that if using a Unicode-aware engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX). For example, the following just works (when compiled with `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ĄąĆćĘę£łŃńÓóŚś-źŻż
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If the problem is that you don't have a convenient (or memorable) keyboard layout for typing that in, so you'd prefer to type using the TeX macros (but would still prefer to have the file contain characters like the above), then this is simply a matter of setting up your editor or input system. For example (suggested in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416672/harnessing-the-tex-compiler-to-write-a-tex-to-utf8-converter/416772#comment1041756_416672) by user Loop Space), Emacs can do this, with `M-x set-input-method RET TeX`: when you hit the keys `\=o` on your keyboard, what gets typed into the file is `ō`. You don't have to use Emacs; this kind of feature is also available in input methods like UIM ([example](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/TeXInputMethodForUnicodeNotations#in-coqide-using-uim-on-posix-systems)).

So I see no reason for using TeX itself to do such conversion, if you're creating the `.tex` file: it would be better to find a way of inserting your preferred characters in the first place.

---

However, the question may make sense if you're working with a `.tex` file created by someone else (and it's ok for you to change the file), or created by yourself from before you had this preference.

The main thing that using TeX (instead of simple search-and-replace in your editor say) gives, is the ability to know when the definitions of macros like `\L` and `\O` have changed. This is also the problem illustrated in the question.

So for solving this, I have the following solution using the introspective (aka [reflective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))) abilities that come with LuaTeX: specifically, `token.get_macro` that lets us the see the definitions of macros, and the `process_input_buffer` callback that lets us examine each line of input (and change it if we like). The idea is:

- Before the text starts, record the “original” definitions of all the known character-replacement macros (`\L`, `\"`, `\c`, etc). This lets us know when they have been redefined.
- For each line in the input, look for those macros that occur in the line, *check whether their definitions have not changed*, and (if so) replace them and their arguments with the appropriate replacements.

So, with the example in the question, in a file called say `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile('rewrite.lua')}

\newcommand\zzz{hello}

\begin{document}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\renewcommand\L{LLL}
\renewcommand\"[1]{#1#1}
\renewcommand\c{c}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\end{document}
```

(note the `\directlua{dofile(...)}` line that was added), you can run `lualatex mwe.tex` (some lines snipped):

```
9:41:29:~/tmp% lualatex mwe.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
...
The original definition of #\L# is \TU-cmd \L \TU\L 
The original definition of #\c# is \TU-cmd \c \TU\c 
The original definition of #\"# is \TU-cmd \"\TU\" 
...
Processing line: \begin{document}
 --> Rewrote line to \begin{document}
...
Processing line: \L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz
 --> Rewrote line to Łööķ \zzz
Processing line: 
 --> Rewrote line to 
Processing line: \renewcommand\L{LLL}
 ^ This line contains a \def or \newcommand or \renewcommand. Not rewriting.
...
Processing line: \L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz
 --> Rewrote line to \L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz
```

And you'll find a `mwe.rewritten.tex` file containing:

```
\newcommand\zzz{hello}

\begin{document}
\relax

Łööķ \zzz

\renewcommand\L{LLL}
\renewcommand\"[1]{#1#1}
\renewcommand\c{c}

\L\"{o}\"{o}\c{k} \zzz

\end{document}
\relax
```

where you can see that only the replacements that should have happened have happened. The Lua file (called `rewrite.lua` above) above that makes this happen is:

```lua
print('')
rewritten_file = io.open(tex.jobname .. '.rewritten.tex', 'w')

funny_noarg = {
   ["\\L"] = "Ł",
   -- Define similarly for \oe \OE \ae \AE \aa \AA \o \O \l \i \j
}
funny_nonletter = {
   ['\\"'] = function(c) return c .. "̈" end,
   -- Define similarly for \` \' \^ \~ \= \.
}
funny_letter = {
   ["\\c"] = function(c) return c .. "̧" end,
   -- Define similarly for \u \v \H \c \d \b \t
}

orig_defs = {}
function populate_orig_defs()
   function set_def(s)
      definition = token.get_macro(s:sub(2))
      orig_defs[s] = definition
      print('The original definition of #' .. s .. '# is ' .. definition)
   end
   for s, v in pairs(funny_noarg) do set_def(s) end
   for s, v in pairs(funny_letter) do set_def(s) end
   for s, v in pairs(funny_nonletter) do set_def(s) end
end
populate_orig_defs()

function literalize(s)
   -- The string s, with special characters escaped, in a format safe for using inside gsub.
   -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745448/lua-plain-string-gsub#comment18401212_1746473
   return s:gsub("[%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$]", "%%%0")
end
function replace(s)
   print('Processing line: ' .. s)
   if s:find([[\def]]) ~= nil or s:find([[\newcommand]]) ~= nil or s:find([[\renewcommand]]) ~= nil then
      print(' ^ This line contains a \\def or \\newcommand or \\renewcommand. Not rewriting.')
     rewritten_file:write(s .. '\n')
     return nil
   end
   for k, v in pairs(funny_noarg) do
      -- followed by a nonletter. TODO: Can use the catcode tables.
      if token.get_macro(k:sub(2)) == orig_defs[k] then
         s = s:gsub(literalize(k) .. '([^a-zA-Z])', function(capture) return v .. capture end)
      end
   end
   for k, v in pairs(funny_letter) do
      -- followed by a letter inside {}. TODO: Can use the catcode tables, also can support \c c, for example.
      if token.get_macro(k:sub(2)) == orig_defs[k] then
         s = s:gsub(literalize(k) .. '{(.)}', v)
      end
   end
   for k, v in pairs(funny_nonletter) do
      -- followed by a letter inside {}. TODO: We could also support \"o for example.
      if token.get_macro(k:sub(2)) == orig_defs[k] then
         s = s:gsub(literalize(k) .. '{(.)}', v)
      end
   end
   print(' --> Rewrote line to ' .. s)
   rewritten_file:write(s .. '\n')
   return nil
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', replace, 'Replace some macros with UTF-8 equivalents')
```

As this is just a proof-of-concept and not a production-quality system I took some shortcuts that you can fill out if you're interested in pursuing this approach:

- Only listed the Unicode equivalents for a few of TeX's accent or special-char macros
- You need to re-insert the `\documentclass{article}` line (and in fact whatever you have before the `\directlua{dofile(…)}` line). (For fun, you can try moving the line *before* `\documentclass` and see what happens.)
- You probably want to have this line after all `\usepackage` lines, maybe at the start of `\begin{document}`. (If you've tried the above you'll know why.)
- You need to remove the `\relax` line at the end (we could probably make this not appear…)
- It assumes that the input file contains LaTeX-convention `\={o}` and not `\=o`; with a few more lines we could support the latter too. Similarly if instead of `\c{k}` we have `\c k` or `\c {k}`, etc.
- It completely ignores (does not replace anything in) lines containing `\def` or `\newcommand`; instead if we wanted (if the input file was so badly written!) we could just skip till the end of the `\def` or whatever, and process the rest.
- It assumes that (to know when a control sequence like `\o` ends) that the “letters” are `a-zA-Z`; you may want to add `@` to that list, and actually we could use the exact definition of “letter” under the catcode regime active at that time — LuaTeX does provide that too.

Note that even if you normally compile your file with pdfTeX or XeTeX, you could use LuaTeX just for this conversion, and go back to using pdfTeX/XeTeX on the converted file.

Comment: Very impressive, though I very seriously doubt that LuaTeX is capable of 'introspection'. I suspect either you meant something else or this term is being used with some sense I'm entirely unfamiliar with. Impressive though the engine is, I seriously question the attribution of self-consciousness. Now, If LuaTeX itself claimed it was introspecting then things might look different, though establishing that it had claimed it would presumably present something of an obstacle.

Comment: @ cfr :-) Good point. Are you a psychologist or philosopher by any chance? :-) How easy it is to forget that one is using jargon picked up from somewhere, leading to strange meanings… I was using “introspection” in the sense that LuaTeX lets you examine TeX internals at runtime to a greater degree than TeX itself. Now I search for the term and can find no clear references, but there's for example the question [How is introspection useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061325/) on Stack Overflow which I realize must seem very strange if reading in the normal sense…

Comment: Philosopher. I also read a lot of psychology. (I work quite a bit on the implications for philosophy of empirical psychology.) Maybe you could explain the term in your answer? (But I can't upvote again if you do, so I have no carrot to offer!)

Comment: @cfr Ah! And thanks :-) I've added a link to “reflective” (best I could find) and also explained what I meant in this context.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'd call it 'reflexive' (in the mathematical/logical function sense), but maybe that's just me. Mind you, this does explain why LuaTeX takes longer than pdfTeX to compile. Only the former is wondering whether it should have done something different with its life.